# how do you parse a string in vb6?

Tags: vb6

Some of us unfortunately are still supporting legacy app like VB6. I have forgotten how to parse a string.

Given a string:

```
Dim mystring As String = "1234567890"
```

How do you loop in VB6 through each character and do something like

```
   for each character in mystring
      debug.print character
   next
```

In C# i would do something like

```
 char[] myChars = mystring.ToCharArray();
 foreach (char c in theChars)
 {
    //do something with c
 }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? Find if something exists in the string? Find the position of a char in the string?

Comment: With each number in the string i need to do something.
debug.print would do the trick for me and I can take it from there
thanks

Comment: In C#, you could iterate over the string without converting it to a char array first: `string mystring = "1234567890"; foreach(char c in mystring) { ... }`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the 'Mid' function to get at the individual characters:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(mystring)
    Print Mid$(mystring, i, 1)
Next
```

Note this is untested.

Comment: Please use `Mid$` instead of `Mid` - It's more efficient and type-safe since no variants are used.

Comment: Sorry - it's been years since I used VB6. I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to use foreach on strings.

Use

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(YourString)
    Result = Mid$(YourString, i, 1)
Next
```

note that the type of `Result` is a length-1 string, no char or byte type.

If performance is important, you'll have to convert the string to a bytearray fist (using `StrConv`) and then loop through it like this.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(Data)
    Result = Data(i) ' Type is Byte '
Next
```

This is much more efficient.

Comment: Be aware that if you convert the string to a byte array using StrConv you are also converting it from Unicode to "ANSI" using the current system code page.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert the string into an array of bytes and iterate over the byte array (converting each byte to a character).

```
Dim str As String
Dim bytArray() As Byte
Dim count As Integer

str = "This is a string."
bytArray = str

For count = 0 To UBound(bytArray)
    Debug.Print Chr(bytArray(count))
Next
```

Comment: Doesn't work like one could expect because theare are lots of empty bytes. Note that you can't apply `Chr` on a byte but only on strings.

Comment: Be aware that if you convert the string to a byte array like that you are also converting it from Unicode to "ANSI" using the current system code page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop; rather, set a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library and use regular expressions to achieve your 'do something' goal.